# TargetElement.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

It's been a very long night, and longer day -- what am I missing to get the events working...?!

```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script>
  var config = {
    SKU_CSV_ENDPOINT: '/cgi-bin/sku-csv-input.cgi'
  };

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var input = document.getElementById('sku-csv');
    var submit = document.getElementById('sku-csv-submit');

    var uploadSkuCsv = function () {
      console.log('Upload SKUs')
      if (input.files.length > 0 && confirm( input.files[0].name )) {
        var file = input.files[0],
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', config.SKU_CSV_ENDPOINT);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
        xhr.send(file);
      }

      input.addEventListener('change', uploadSkuCsv, false);
    }
  });
</script>
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <h1>Maps Updater</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <label for="sku-csv">Choose a SKU CSV to upload.</label>

    <input id="sku-csv" name="sku-csv"
      type="file" placeholder="SKU CSV file"
      accept=".csv"
    >
    <button id="sku-csv-submit">Update Map</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```

Comment: `input.addEventListener('change', uploadSkuCsv, false);` is inside `uploadSkuCsv`, so it will never be called. If it’s been a long day, you really should take a break, not spam Stack Overflow with questions about trivial errors.

Comment: Thanks so much for the life advice, Xufox. What would I do without gurus like you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addEventLister is inside the function which should be added.
just change to:

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var input = document.getElementById('sku-csv');
    var submit = document.getElementById('sku-csv-submit');

    var uploadSkuCsv = function () {
      console.log('Upload SKUs')

    }

      input.addEventListener('change', uploadSkuCsv, false);
  });
```